# TypeError: no numeric data to plot- plotting dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am getting the following type of error: **no numeric data to plot**

When trying to plot the data frame

```
df_prevalence.head()
```

|  | State | Percent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | New Jersey | 3.41 |
| 1 | Florida | 3.49 |
| 2 | New York | 3.68 |
| 3 | Texas | 3.72 |
| 4 | Illinois | 3.87 |

The code I used

```
df_prevalence.plot(kind='barh', x='Percent', y='State', figsize=(15, 12), color='r', title= 'Adults with Serious Thoughts of Suicide in the Unites States by State, 2020')
plt.xlabel('Prevalence (%)')
plt.ylabel('State')
```

reproducible example input:

```
df_prevalence = pd.DataFrame({'Percent': [3.41, 3.49, 3.68, 3.72, 3.87],
                              'State': ['New Jersey', 'Florida', 'New York',
                                        'Texas', 'Illinois ']})
```

Comment: can you provide the output of `df_prevalence.head().to_dict('list')`?

Comment: ```{'Percent': [3.41, 3.49, 3.68, 3.72, 3.87],
 'State': ['New Jersey', 'Florida', 'New York', 'Texas', 'Illinois ']}```

Answer (score 0):

You likely inverted the x and y:

```
ax = df_prevalence.plot(kind='barh', y='Percent', x='State', ...)
```

output (with smaller size):

[image]